# question about adding characters in a loop

Tags: python, loops

I’m in an intro to programming class and am trying to figure out how to write code that will build a triangle based on user input height and character.  This is what I started doing but it’s going to fail because I cannot figure out how to print multiple characters per line based on the user height input.  Any ideas on what I need to change?  The book isn’t much help and I am still unfamiliar with proper terminology so my searching hasnt turned up anything useful, thanks!

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')
i = 0
while i <= 0:
    if i > triangle_height:
        break
    print(triangle_char)
    i = i + 1 
    if i == 1:
        print(triangle_char, triangle_char)
        i = i + 1
    if i == 2:
        print(triangle_char, triangle_char, triangle_char)
```

Comment: You're going to need a loop within a loop, and print `i` characters.

Comment: Can you show us what the triangle is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your working code properly, I guess you want a right angled triangle. You can in that case use a single `for` loop and use `join` to put spaces `" "` between the characters. `triangle_char*i` repeats the character `i` number of times where `i` ranges from `1` to `triangle_height`.

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range(1, triangle_height + 1):
    print(" ".join(triangle_char*i))
```

---

```
Enter a character:
*
Enter triangle height:
6

*             # ^
* *           # | 
* * *         # | height = 6
* * * *       # | 
* * * * *     # |
* * * * * *   # v
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  This helped me greatly!

Answer (score 0):

There are really a thousand ways to do what you want here. Here is an example to create a symmetric triangle:

```
def draw_line(i, char, total_height):

    if i == total_height:
        print ( char * (2 * total_height - 1) )
        return None

    side = (total_height - i) * " "

    if i == 1:
        middle = char
    else :
        middle = char + (2*i - 3) * " " + char

    print( side + middle + side )
    return None


def create_triangle(char="*",  height=5):

    for i in range(1, height+1):
        draw_line(i, char, height)

    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_triangle("^", 7)
```

This outputs:

```
      ^      
     ^ ^     
    ^   ^    
   ^     ^   
  ^       ^  
 ^         ^ 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

With a scripting language like Python, you can easily manipulate your strings with a bench of useful functions. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this info!  It will definitely help me with the next part of this assignment!